# How to send Http Delete Request with json content inside it

Tags: firefox, http, firefox-extensions

I am using Firefox addon [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) to send HTPP Delete Request with json content inside it but after generating the request, it is completely ignoring the content data passed in the request.

So how to pass send Http Delete Request with **some content inside it**, is there some other addon or toll which i can use locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/restclient/), probably will do the work better

Comment: Thanks, sorry can't upvote ur answer as my points are below 15.
StackoverflowAdmins can you please allow users to Upvote an answer for there own question :)

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help you with solution :)